# Can't get any files from the downloads directory

Tags: android, storage, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to build a simple gallery that shows all images from a certain directory `downloads/mCustomDir`.

But even without trying to access this custom directory, and just trying to access the general downloads directory, I am getting no files back even though I know that there are files there.
There seems to be a lot of changes in how to access storage in the last few months and a lot of things deprecated, so I am having a hard time understanding how to access these files properly.

This is my function:

```
private fun loadSavedImages(dir: File?) {
    if (dir != null) {
        if (dir.exists()) {
            val files = dir.listFiles()
            if (files != null) {
                val allPhotos = mutableListOf<File>()
                Log.d("filesListSize", files.size.toString())

                for (file in files) {
                    val absolutePath = file.absolutePath

                    val extension = absolutePath.substring(absolutePath.lastIndexOf("."))
                    if (acceptedExtensions.contains(extension)) {
                        allPhotos.add(file)
                    }
                }
                allPhotosViewModel.photosList.postValue(allPhotos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I can on `onResume`:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if (hasNoPermissions(this)) {
        requestPermission(this, permissions)
    } else {
        if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
            runOnUiThread {
                loadSavedImages(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bus the log keeps printing that the size of the files array is 0.

When I use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` it works fine but it is deprecated and I'd rather it build by the best current standards.

Comment: If there are no images in the path indicated by getExternalFilesDir() then you code will find nothing. Did you put images there? No one else would.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` I think that directory does not even exist(you can check that before calling loadSavedImages()) be it that you created that directory earlier.

Comment: You should log or toast the absolute paths of the directories you try to list. Use File.getAbsolutePath(). Then you will know better what you are doing.

Comment: OK, so I understand that `getExternalFilesDir` should give me files that were added by my app, correct? So that's not what I want. I want public files under the download folder. As mentioned in my question, `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` works just fine for that but it's deprecated. Wherever I look for what to use instead of it, I see `getExternalFilesDir` as the answer. So I'm just confused here.

Comment: That is a wrong answer for you as that would be a solution if you want to store your files somewhere. You can only use getExternalStorageDirectory() for the things you want. If your app is under construction then go away from classic filepaths now and use SAF (Storage Access Framework) to list the files in the primary partition or where ever. The fuction is deprecated and soon all is Android Q or higher where it does not run at all. Use saf or query the MediaStore. Start now.